# How to echo #!/ using shell or bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to print `#!/` via Bash, but it doesn't print it and instead prints the following.

```
parth@parth-ubuntu64:$ echo "#!\/"
bash: !\/: event not found
```

EDITED: 
Allow me to make one more update. How do you make the following work? I think I should just use python instead of bash. The reason why I am trying to do this is because, I want to pipe this into a file which requires sudo permission. This is the only way I can execute sudo => sudo sh -c " echo something > file "

```
sh -c 'echo \'#!/bin/bash \' '
```

Comment: You just want to echo those literal characters?

Comment: With single quotes: `echo '#!/'`.

Comment: maybe this `echo '#!\/'`

Comment: You can also escape the exclamation mark: `echo \#\!/`.

Comment: Re: your edit: `sh -c 'echo "#!/bin/bash"'` will work: `sh` has no history like Bash, and in this line, the `!` is in the single quoted string, so you won't have history expansion.

Comment: You can use `tee` to work around the permission issue: `echo '#!/bin/bash' | sudo tee target-file > /dev/null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within double quotes (and with history expansion enabled), the `!` has special meaning. To print those characters literally, use single quotes instead of double:

```
$ echo '#!\/'
#!\/
```

History expansion can be disabled in the interactive shell by using `set +H`, which allows you to use double quotes:

```
$ set +H
$ echo "#!\/"
#!\/
```

In general, if you do not require variables to be interpolated (such as in this case), you should use single quotes.

Note that it is not necessary to escape the `/`, so you can remove the `\` from before it if your desired output is `#!/`:

```
$ echo '#!/'
#!/
```

Answer (score 2):

In an interactive shell `!` is subject to history expansion. For example, `!!` is the last command you typed and `!$` is the last argument to that command. To avoid history expansion, escape the `!` with a backslash or use single quotes.

```
echo '#!/'
```

This isn't necessary in shell scripts, only in interactive shells (unless you purposefully enable `set -o history` and `set -o histexpand` in the shell script).

> Allow me to make one more update. How do you make the following work?
>
> ```
> sh -c 'echo \'#!/bin/bash \' '
> ```

There's no way to have a single quote inside single quotes. `\'` doesn't work. So back to double quotes we go.

```
sh -c "echo '#\!/bin/bash'"
```

Comment: You can also swap the `'` and `"` as in my comment to the OP: `sh -c 'echo "#!/bin/bash"'`

Answer (score 1):

Some things are interpreted inside double quotes, including both backslashes and history events introduced by an exclamation mark. Use the more powerful single quotes instead:

```
echo '#!\/'
```

Comment: Actually I understand now what you were trying to say. :) It does work

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the text inside single quotes, so that it won't parse.

```
$ echo '#!/'
#!/
$ echo '#!\/'
#!\/
```

Answer (score 0):

use single quotes instead of double.

```
echo '#!/'
```